# MYSQL query to sum multiple columns in different tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, where-clause

I have two tables (orders, order_lines) with a one to many relationship. The orders table will have one row and the order_lines table will have one row for each product attached to the order.

ORDERS

```
   +----------+-------------+---------------+
   |order_num | total_order | shipping_total|
   +----------+-------------+---------------+
   | 12345    | 75.00       | 15.00         |
   +----------+-------------+---------------+
```

ORDER_LINES

```
   +----------+-------------+-------+
   | order_num| volume      | price |
   +----------+-------------+-------+
   | 12345    |10           |25.00  |
   +----------+-------------+-------+
   | 12345    |20           |25.00  |
   +----------+-------------+-------+
   | 12345    |20           |25.00  |
   +----------+-------------+-------+
```

I would like to sum the total_order & shipping_total columns in the ORDERS table and the volume & price columns in the ORDER_LINES table.

Query currently not working:

```
SELECT b_orders.bill_country, b_orders.ship_country
    , SUM(volume) AS v, SUM(price) AS pt
    , SUM(shipping_total) AS st, SUM(total_order) AS tot_o 
FROM b_orders 
JOIN b_order_lines 
    ON b_orders.order_num = b_order_lines.order_num 
WHERE DATE(b_orders.order_date) BETWEEN '2012-04-02' AND '2012-04-06' 
    AND ship_country = 'USA' 
    AND b_order_lines.price > 0;
```

This query is returning the wrong values. I kind of know why but have no idea how to write the proper query...please help.

Comment: Do you want the grand total or pr. Order or pr. country?

Comment: The intermediate table produced by the join will create three rows, each with the same value for total_order and shipping_total.  So your SUM() will triple-count these quantities, but it will give you the correct total for volume.  Adding up price like this doesn't make sense to me.  Generally, you don't want to SUM() across your header table (ORDERS) and your detail table (ORDER_LINES) in the same query.

Comment: Ah, I see that price is what I would call extended_price.  It's volume * a unit price column that I can't see.

Comment: So what should I do? Is there a way to make this work as I can't redesign the database.

Comment: Can you not execute two separate queries and put the results together in your PHP script?

Answer (score 3):

When you use an aggregate function line `SUM`, you need to tell the SQL server what columns are going to be used to `GROUP BY` for doing the sums.

So if you add the following to the bottom of your query:

```
GROUP BY
  b_orders.bill_country, b_orders.ship_country
```

This will tell it to give you the sum for each unique combination of `bill_country, ship_country` in the data.  Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If bill_country and ship_country are going to be included in a query that also has aggregate functions like SUM, you need to group on them.  I suspect all you need is to add this line at the end:

```
GROUP BY  b_orders.bill_country, b_orders.ship_country;
```

If you don't need to see them, you can remove them from the SELECT statement and omit the grouping; you don't have to select columns to include them in the WHERE clause.